# Trouble with structs in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct, malloc

I'm having troubles with this code.
Basically I must create a structure with dynamic strings,then ask user to assingn memory for each string. After that, ask user his name,surname and city, convert all strings to mayus using strupr(), and finally, print it.

```
/*16.ask user his name,surname and city. Then,convert all to MAYUS(with strupr()), and print all data(use a structure and dynamic memory).*/

#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct data{
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    char *city;
}user;

void flush_in();

int main(){
    int n1,n2,n3;

    printf("type memory for name: ");
    scanf("%i",&n1);
    user.name=malloc(sizeof(int)*n1);

    printf("type memory for surname: ");
    scanf("%i",&n2);
    user.surname=malloc(sizeof(int)*n2);

    printf("type memory for city: ");
    scanf("%i",&n3);
    user.city=malloc(sizeof(int)*n3);
    flush_in();
    printf("type name: ");
    scanf("% [^\n]",&user.name);
    flush_in();

    printf("type surname: ");
    scanf("% [^\n]",&user.surname);
    flush_in();

    printf("type city: ");
    scanf("% [^\n]",&user.city);

    strupr(user.name);
    strupr(user.surname);
    strupr(user.city);

    printf("\nname: %s",user.name);
    printf("\nsurname: %s",user.surname);
    printf("\ncity: %s",user.city);

    return 0;
}

void flush_in(){
       int ch;
       while((ch=fgetc(stdin))!=EOF && ch!='\n'){}
}
```

Everything is fine until the output, it returns:

`name: : P¡`
`surname: P¡`
`city: P¡`

why it this happen? It's suposed to return my name, surname and city, but I don't know what is the error.

Comment: There should be no space after the `%` in `scanf`. Note that `scanf` returns the number of successful conversions. You should check that. I expect that all of your `scanf` are returning 0.

Comment: Post your sample input too.  It helps a lot and it gains better feedback.

Comment: regarding: `struct data{
    char *name;
    char *surname;
    char *city;
}user;`  it is best to separate the definition of a struct from an instance of the struct.

Comment: regarding: `printf("\nname: %s",user.name);`  except for when a specific format is desired, it is best to write similar to: `printf("name: %s\n",user.name);`  so the data will be immediately output (to the terminal) rather than sitting in the system output buffer until a '\n' or 'flush( stdout );' or the program exits

Comment: Your `malloc()` is wrong too. Should be `malloc(sizeof(char) * n1)` and the same for others. This is better suited for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: regarding: `user.city=malloc(sizeof(int)*n3);`  1) In a 32 bit architecture, a `int` is 4 bytes, so this kind of statement is allocating some 4 times the amount of memory specified by the user.  suggest: `user.city=malloc(n3 +1);`  The `+1` to allow for the trailing NUL byte.  2) when calling any of the heap allocation functions: `malloc` `calloc` `realloc`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer,  the expressiion `sizeof(char)` is defined in the C standard as 1.  Multiplying anything by 1 has no effect.  However, it does clutter the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc

Comment: the function: `malloc()` and family expect a parameter of type `size_t`, not `int`  (correcting this problem will involve changing the type of the variables to `size_t` and changing the `scanf()` format string to `%zu` (or similar)

Comment: I'm on Linux.  There does not seem to be a function: `strupr()`

Comment: @user3629249 - C99 6.5.3.4 forces `sizeof(char)` to be 1. Thanks.

Comment: @user3629249 I think OP is trying this on DOS or MSVC.

Comment: when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Other compilers will have their own options to accomplish the same thing

Comment: The `&` operators should not be present in the calls to `scanf`.  Since each of those `struct` members is a pointer, using `&user.name` passes the address of the pointer itself to `scanf` rather than the "payload" of the pointer, i.e. address of the first byte of the  character array returned by `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, I've corrected the mistakes, and changed the "scanf()" for a "fgets()", it works perfectly!!!

Comment: @chux I'll take in consideration for the next time! I'm new un this community and I'm learning a lot of C programming.

Comment: @dgnuff that's true, I've forgotten that, hahaha. Thank you so much!

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer yes, you're right, thank you!

Comment: @user3629249 oh, thank you, I didn't know that. Now I'm gonna practice with that!

Comment: @UnmannedPlayer well, I was trying this on Windows(yes, I'm a little newbie un OS, haha). On the future I want to learn about Linux OS...